# Counting frequency of specific value in selected columns of an attribute table of the feature class in ArcGIS 10.4

Tags: arcpy, field-calculator, count, frequency

I want to calculate the number of members in the houses (feature class which contain information of the members in the house interms of age,sex,occupation) based on the information entered in age column (if the column contain -9999 then there is no person in the house) as shown in following table
[image]

For this task i have used Model Builder as shown below but due to the NULL values generated in the process of calculation, I could not get the exact output.
Are there any ways to do this using Python?
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: those age columns are in the format of long and double not in string

Comment: Why does the question title ask about "string or number" if the data is actually integer or double?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An arcpy solution can be:

```
import arcpy

feature_class = r'C:\database.db\features'
field_to_update = 'members'

#List all fields containing Age in field name
fields = [f.name for f in arcpy.ListFields(feature_class) if 'Age' in f.name]
fields.append(field_to_update)

#Count fields with values >0 and update field_to_update
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(feature_class, fields) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        row[-1] = sum(1 for x in row[:-1] if x > 0)
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```

Which you also can add in your model: [Integrating scripts within a model](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/modelbuilder/integrating-scripts-within-a-model.htm)

Comment: getting the error :TypeError: 'field_names' must be string or non-empty sequence of strings" are there any problem with name of the field?

Comment: yes, field names have "Age" in them, and filed aliases too

Comment: it is not empty after add print fields  it shows all the fields contain "Age"   as follows >>> print fields
[u'F1_HH_Age', u'F1_M1_Age', u'F1_M2_Age', u'F1_M3_Age', u'F1_M4_Age', u'F1_M5_Age', u'F1_M6_Age', u'F1_M7_Age', u'F1_M8_Age', u'F1_M9_Age', u'F1_M10_Age', u'F2_M1_Age', u'F2_M2_Age', u'F2_M3_Age', u'F2_M4_Age', u'F2_M5_Age', u'F2_M6_Age', u'F2_M7_Age', u'F3_M1_Age', u'F3_M2_Age', u'F3_M3_Age', u'F3_M4_Age', u'F3_M5_Age']

Comment: it works as i expected, many thanks for your valuable support